# Routes component from react-router-dom not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

ALERT: My english is not good.

Hello everybody, I'm getting started with React and I installed react-router-dom for my project. I read the documentation and I have followed step by step what it said, but is not work for me. The problem is when I add  in App.js.

This is my App.js component:

```js
import '.App.css'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './views/home/Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome to React Router !</h1>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

and my Home component is:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Home() {
    return(
        <>
            <main>
                <h1>Welcome to Lukson Passwords</h1>
                <p>You can do this, I believe in you.</p>
            </main>
            <nav>
                <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
}

export default Home();
```

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This not work, when I load my page this one shows nothing, but if I delete  from my App.js it works fine.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Thank you so much, and sorry for my english xd

Comment: Please share your code, we can't help debug what we can't see. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Need to see your App.tsx and package.json version of react-router-dom

Comment: Only thing I see missing/unverified is a router wrapping your app code somewhere to provide a routing context for the routes and links. Are you wrapping `App` with a `BrowserRouter` or similar in your `index.js` file? If it's missing then you should be seeing errors in the console informing you as such.

Comment: Yes, I have configured BrowserRouter in Index.js but It doesn't work either :/

Comment: Ok, then we've not enough code context. Can you update your question to include all of your routing/navigation code? Do you have any errors? Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue have that we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your app with `BrowserRouter`. Let's see what happens when you do that

Comment: Yes, I have configured the BrowserRouter inside index.js but it doesn't work either :(